# Differential equation, a square root and substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got a differential equation to solve: $\frac{dy}{dx} x =\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$. I substitute $w=\frac{y}{x}$ and I obtain after several steps: $\frac{dw}{\sqrt{1+w^2} -w} = \frac{dx}{x}$, and the integral from left hand side is really unpleasent thing to compute. Do I solve it in the right way? Is my result correct and I should continue doing it this way? Please, can somebody check and help me with solving it?

Comment: It looks good. Maybe just to say $x>0$ when $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}=\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}$$

Comment: Yes, true. So I will just compute this integral, although it looks quite sophisticated to me.

Comment: Wolfram says that solution for differential equation is "ugly", like integral, so all the best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your equation is
$$
y'x = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
If you do substitution $w = \frac yx$ as you stated you'll get
$$
y = wx \\
y' = w'x+w \\
w'x+w = \text{sign}(x)\sqrt{1+w^2} \\
w' = \frac {\text{sign}(x)\sqrt{1+w^2}-w}x \\
\frac {dw}{{\text{sign}(x)\sqrt{1+w^2}-w}} = \frac {dx}x \\
dw \left({\text{sign}(x)\sqrt{1+w^2}+w} \right) = \frac {dx}x \\
\frac {w^2}2 + \int \left (\text{sign}(x)\sqrt{1+w^2} \right) dw = \ln |x| 
$$
Now do another substitution
$$
w = \sinh t \\
dw = \cosh t\ dt \\
\int \left (\text{sign}(x)\sqrt{1+w^2} \right) dw = \text{sign}(x) \int \cosh^2 tdt = \text{sign}(x) \int \frac {1+\cosh 2t}2dt = \\
= \text{sign}(x) \left( \frac t2 + \frac 14 \sinh 2t\right) = \frac{\text{sign}(x)}2\left ( \text{arcsinh }w + w\sqrt{1+w^2}\right)
$$
So final equation is
$$
w^2 + \text{sign}(x)\left (\text{arcsinh }w + w\sqrt{1+w^2}\right) = \ln x^2 + C
$$
I don't think you can go any further than that, so all is left is substitute $y$ and $x$ to the solution.
$$
\frac {y^2}{x^2} + \text{arcsinh }(\frac y{|x|}) + y \sqrt{x^2+y^2} - \ln x^2 = C
$$

Comment: If you use $\text{sign}(x)$ on every place, than write $\ln |x|$ if you want to be formal :)

Comment: @Cortizol right, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+w^2}-w} = \sqrt{1+w^2}+w$$

Comment: Well. I already computed this integral. And my result is just like in wolfram. But I faced the next step, which is obtaining $w$ from this equation... Anybody any idea how to do it, while I have everything there: inverse of hiperbolic sinus, square root and so on...?