# Differential equation with square root, how to use $\\sgn()$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know I should do some substitution and then somehow use $\text{sign}(\cdot)$ function to solve this, but I have no idea. My problem is the $\text{sign}(\cdot)$ function. I found this answer [Differential equation, a square root and substitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330642/differential-equation-a-square-root-and-substitution), but I don't know how he extracted $\text{sign}(\cdot)$ under the square root.

$$x y' - y = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Following the similar path the link takes, let $w=\frac{y}{x}$. Then
\begin{align}
wx &= y \\
\implies xw'+w &= y'
\end{align}
hence your ODE becomes
\begin{align}
x(w+xw') - wx &= \sqrt{x^2\left(1+w^2\right)} \\
\implies x^2 w' &= \operatorname{sgn}(x)\sqrt{1+w^2}
\end{align}
Where the Signum funciton is defined as
$$\operatorname{sgn}(x) := \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } x < 0, \\
0 & \text{if } x = 0, \\
1 & \text{if } x > 0. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanxs, but It looked so unnatural for me that only extracting $\\x^2$ would be enough. Can you tell me, what rule allows me to subtract it out as $\\sign(x)$.